# Wild card searches with query_string

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to enable wild card queries by default using query_string?

I'm having to manually append * to each of the terms. I had a look at the documentation but couldn't find anything.

Comment: can you post query and mapping?

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat Thank you but the query and mapping are irrelevant I would just like to know if it's possible to enable wild card queries by default so that you don't have to append * to terms.

Comment: Prefix search is what you need https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to enable it. You can enable/disable using wildcards "allow_leading_wildcard" the way how it works, that ES try to match [tokens](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/language-intro.html). So if you search for **car** it will match **car** until you search car* then it will match **cars** (sure it depends on analysis but further there is link for you to read).

I dont know case what you want to do but you should look [to dealing with language](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/languages.html). It should help also note that using leading wildcard could have performance issues that is why sometimes is better to disable it.